# Control a stepper motor with a 3-phase controller

Tags: stepper-motor

Is it possible to run a stepper motor with a closed loop 3-phase controller? What i have seen is, that some people short A- with B-, so that it is tranformed into a 2 coil 3 phase system. So i tried this myself with a field oriented control inverter with absolute position sensing, but I had no success yet. If this is possible, what would be the number of pole pairs for a normal 1.8°/step stepper motor?

This is what I found here (http://ijcsiet.com/pdf/01082014-026.pdf):[image]

Comment: A two-coil motor can only be a 2-phase motor, not a 3-phase motor.

Comment: But if the controller is 3-phase, why should it not be possible to control a 2-phase motor with it?

Comment: A three phase source has a 120 degree displacement between phases and a two-phase source has 180 degrees. I believe that using using only two of the three phases would result in pulsating torque.

Comment: Ok, there you are right. But should it be not possible to project two phases on one coil and the third phase to the other coil?

Comment: I think the motor could be operated by connecting to just two of the three phases if some kind of irregular fast stepping is acceptable. The controller would need to be tolerant of the open phase and would probably need an open-loop operating mode. You probably can not treat it as a synchronous motor. Perhaps someone will come along with a real answer within the next 24 hours or so.

Comment: I have the same problem. wanted to replace Leadshine DM542 with Leadshine 3DM580. :/ I guess i cant then